# Choosing a technique for solids of revolution

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

Is there a heuristic to choose between the disk method and the washer method? To take the simplest example $y=x$ can be revolved around the $y$ axis using $R=x$ or $r=x$ and $R=$ a constant $C$.

Comment: The disk method and the method of washers are essentially the same. Do you really mean disk/washer versus cylindrical shells?

Comment: Well not originally but that is another layer to the onion - is there a rule for when to use that?

Comment: Suppose we are rotating about the $y$-axis, and $y=f(x)$ is involved. If in $y=f(x)$ it is unpleasant or impossible to solve explicitly for $x$ in terms of $y$, then cylindrical shells will likely be better than  slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in doubt, try both far enough to see which one is easier. I doubt there is any simple rule of thumb.

In any case, trying out both for a collection of cases will help you get a feel when each technique is more appropriate. Maybe you even come up with the requested criteria yourself ;-)